# iPython Notebook in Windows - Error on Startup

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying desperately to get ipython notebook to work in a windows environment.  I installed Continuum IO's Anaconda, a scientific distribution of python.  I want to use ipython notebook, but get the following error.  `ipython` in the terminal works fine.  Any thoughts?

UPDATE:  As asked for below, here is the output from sys.path on my system.

```
['',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\scripts',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\distribute-0.6.45-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Anaconda',
 'C:\\Users\\btibert\\ C:\\Anaconda\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Users\\btibert\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\btibert\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages\\Orange\\orng',
 'C:\\Users\\btibert\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\btibert\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions']
```

And here is the error:

```
C:\Users\btibert>ipython notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\Scripts\ipython-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(launch_new_instance())
  File "C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\IPython\frontend\terminal\ipapp.py", line 402, in
 launch_new_instance
    app.initialize()
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 84, in catch
_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\IPython\frontend\terminal\ipapp.py", line 302, in
 initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 84, in catch
_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 325, in initia
lize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\IPython\frontend\terminal\ipapp.py", line 297, in
 parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 84, in catch
_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 413, in pars
e_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 84, in catch
_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 349, in init
ialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\IPython\utils\importstring.py", line 40, in impor
t_item
    module = __import__(package,fromlist=[obj])
  File "C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\IPython\frontend\html\notebook\notebookapp.py", l
ine 34, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop.ioloop import IOLoop
  File "C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 56, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop.platform.auto import set_close_exec, Waker
ImportError: No module named platform.auto
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out one way to attack this.  I didn't really think I would have to get this level, but I completely uninstalled every single possible instance of python I could find.  I

1. unisntalled Anaconda CE
2. removed every reference to python in `PATH`
3. edited my registry to clear out python data (but did leave Python folders)
4. Removed python from the App/Roaming path outlined above by @IanSR

Basically, I removed every possible reference to python I could find and then re-installed Anaconda CE.  Voila, the Anaconda install (appears) to have worked as intended by the distributors.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what your `sys.path` is.  You can find that by doing:

```
$ ipython

In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.path
```

And then share here the output.  Next, you want to check what files you have in this directory:

```
C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\platform
```

Ideally, you'll see `auto.py` there, and if `C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages` is in your sys.path then it is a mystery why it isn't working, but if that file isn't there, the directory doesn't exist, or the path to `site-packages` isn't in your `sys.path`, then those need to be resolved first.

Let us know and we can try to take it from there!

Comment: Thanks for the response and many apologies for not replying sooner.  I posted what I see in sys.path above.  In addition, after going to directory, I dont have a the file auto.py nor do I have the directory platform.  Does this help?  Again, many thanks!