# IPython Notebook error - startup fails on Windows 8.1

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I already had Python 2.7 installed on my windows 8.1 machine, which has been there since a long time ago. Recently I installed ipython using the following command in cmd
`pip install ipython`
after which I wanted to use ipython notebook for which I ran the following command in cmd
`ipython notebook`

However on doing so I got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python27\Scripts\ipython-script.py", line 9, in 
>   load_entry_point('ipython==2.3.1', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
>   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-2.3.1-py2.7.egg\IPython__init__.p
>   y", line 120, in start_ipython return launch_new_instance(argv=argv,
>   **kwargs) File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-2.3.1-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\app
>   lication.py", line 563, in launch_instance app.initialize(argv) File
>   "", line 2, in initialize File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-2.3.1-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\app
>   lication.py", line 92, in catch_config_error return method(app, *args,
>   **kwargs) File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-2.3.1-py2.7.egg\IPython\terminal\i
>   papp.py", line 321, in initialize super(TerminalIPythonApp,
>   self).initialize(argv) File "", line 2, in initialize File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-2.3.1-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\app
>   lication.py", line 92, in catch_config_error return method(app, *args,
>   **kwargs) File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-2.3.1-py2.7.egg\IPython\core\appli
>   cation.py", line 381, in initialize self.parse_command_line(argv) File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-2.3.1-py2.7.egg\IPython\terminal\i
>   papp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line return
>   super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv) File
>   "", line 2, in parse_command_line File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-2.3.1-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\application.py",
>   line 92, in catch_config_error return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-2.3.1-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\app
>   lication.py", line 475, in parse_command_line return
>   self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv) File "", line 2, in
>   initialize_subcommand File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-2.3.1-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\application.py",
>   line 92, in catch_config_error return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-2.3.1-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\app
>   lication.py", line 406, in initialize_subcommand subapp =
>   import_item(subapp) File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-2.3.1-py2.7.egg\IPython\utils\impo
>   rtstring.py", line 42, in import_item module = **import**(package,
>   fromlist=[obj]) File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-2.3.1-py2.7.egg\IPython\html\noteb
>   ookapp.py", line 40, in  check_for_zmq('2.1.11',
>   'IPython.html') File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-2.3.1-py2.7.egg\IPython\utils\zmqr
>   elated.py", line 37, in check_for_zmq raise ImportError("%s requires
>   pyzmq >= %s"%(required_by, minimum_version))ImportError: IPython.html
>   requires pyzmq >= 2.1.11

Note: I am just getting started with using ipython, notebook, jupyter etc for my course and have little idea about the issue. I apologise if I am missing something over here, and am grateful for all the help I receive.
In addition I had even gone through the link: "[iPython Notebook in Windows - Error on Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276670/ipython-notebook-in-windows-error-on-startup)" but could not resolve the issue

Comment: Try to install the missing dependency (indicated at the very end of your error message): `pip install pyzmq`

Comment: @paljenczy I did that but that didn't work. So I did `pip uninstall ipython` and then `pip install "ipython[all]" ` and now, unfortunately I am getting the following error and nothing seems to work: 
**Could not find  a version that satisfies the requirement simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipython) (from versions: 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8.1)**